# Create a one level nesting in react for table component based on the retreived data using API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of nested objects. I am using react table component to get the data displayed in tabular format. I am sending the data via tbodyData props and rendering in a tabular format.

```
 [{
    "name": "eth-0/0",
    "tenant-id": 0,
    "if-admin-status": "up",
    "if-oper-status": "down",
    "host-inf": "eth0",
    "rx-stats": {
      "rx-packets": "0",
      "rx-pps": "0",
      "rx-bytes": "0",
      "rx-errors": "0",
      "rx-bps": "0"
    },
    "tx-stats": {
      "tx-packets": "0",
      "tx-pps": "0",
      "tx-bytes": "0",
      "tx-errors": "0",
      "tx-bps": "0"
    }
  },]
```

How can I achieve using maps for one level nested objects using the table component  in react/JSX as displayed below. This component works fine without nesting.

```
export default function Table({theadData, tbodyData}) {
       

    return (
      <table style={{border:"1px solid"}}>
          <thead style={{border:"1px solid", 
     backgroundColor:"rgb(10,110,253)", color:"white"}}>
             <tr style={{border:"1px solid"}}>
              {theadData.map(heading => {
                return<th key={heading}>{heading}</th>
              })}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {tbodyData.map((row, index) => {
                  return<tr key={index} style={(index % 2) ? { 
                backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2' } : null}>
                      {theadData.map((key, index) => {
                           return<td style={{border:"1px 
              solid"}} key={uuidv4()}>{row[key]} </td>
                      })}
                </tr>;
              })}
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

I tried various nesting examples from different forums but none of them are working for me.

Comment: Sorry I missed the array block. Edited

Comment: I *guess* you have some property names like "tenant-id" in your theadData.  So I can see why that would make nested fields not work, `row[key]` isn't suitable for accessing nested fields.  You would need to implement some system like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-and-arrays-by-string-path)